# Как самому добавить динамическую запись в ARP-таблицу?

Tags: windows, сеть, arp

Как при помощи утилит/окон/служб Windows 10 добавить в ARP-таблицу динамическую запись? При помощи утилиты arp можно добавить статическую запись( arp -s). Но как добавить ДИНАМИЧЕСКУЮ. P.S. Да, я понимаю, что в этом нет смысла, но это как-то можно сделать, но не знаю как(

Answer (score 1):

чтоб добавить динамическую запись нужно получить arp пакет на интерфейсе.

Используя другой хост можно произвести атаку на arp https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP-spoofing

Comment: А каким образом это можно сделать руками?

Comment: добавить ip на другом компьютере и пингануть его)